# magento 2 how to use mailchimp programatically only for newsletter

Tags: magento2.3, newsletter, mailchimp, newsletter-subscriber

We need to use 2 email service 
MailChimp for newsletter

and other for SendGrid

SendGrid is working fine but needs to manage how we can use MailChimp only for newsletter?
Which thing needs to override controller, blocks, etc...?

Comment: Try to reverse engineer the ebizmarts mailchimp extension. Regardless of what you do it is going to be a lot of work.

Comment: @DominicXigen can i use plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following for the integration

https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/

Or you can create the same form in your Mailchimp account and use the form action in your newsletter module.

https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/mailchimp-form-action-url/

https://www.codexworld.com/add-subscriber-to-list-mailchimp-api-php/

http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/integrate-the-mailchimp-api-with-your-php-application/

Comment: ok trying this and let you know